# Pause code until getting the response of an UIAlertController in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, alert, pause

I have been trying to get the answer from a user from the UIAlertController. The problem is that the code still runs while the UIAlertController is displayed. I would like to show the alert, and then wait until the user gives an answer to continue the code.

```
func showPopUp(name:String)->String{
   var genre = ""
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What are you "+name+"?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Boy", style: .default, handler: { action in
    genre = "Boy"
}))

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Girl", style: .default, handler: { action in
    genre = "Girl"
}))

   self.present(alert, animated: true)
   return genre
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("This should appear before the alert")
        let a = showPopUp(name: "John)

        print("This should appear after the response")
        print("John is a "+a)
        [...more code using variable 'a' ...]


}
```

I cannot put the code inside the action of the alert because is very long, and it also runs in other processes.

Comment: Use the completion closure to wait till the user tap a button.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts don't work as you might expect , it supposes to ask the user and waits for his action , so it's asynchronous

```
var genre = "Boy" // default

func showPopUp(name:String) {

   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What are you "+name+"?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Boy", style: .default, handler: { action in
       self.genre = "Boy" 
       self.handleSelection() 
   }))

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Girl", style: .default, handler: { action in
       self.genre = "Girl" 
       self.handleSelection()
   }))

   self.present(alert, animated: true)

}

func handleSelection() {
  print("current selected genre is \(genre)")
}
```

Plus this

```
showPopUp(name: "John")
```

should be inside `viewDidAppear` as it's too early to present anything inside `viewDidLoad` where vc' views is yet to be laid completely

```
var once = true
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
  super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  if once {
     showPopUp(name: "John")
     once = false // to prevent re-showing it again
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot put the code inside the action of the alert

Yes, you can, and that is what you *must* do. The action *is* your signal that the alert has been dismissed (and it also tells you what button was tapped in the alert). You don't have to put the code *itself* inside the action; all you need is to *call* that code.

Example:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Boy", style: .default, handler: { action in
    self.myVeryLongFunction(genre:"Boy")
}))
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a separate function, and call it from teh completion handler for your actions.

like this

```
func showPopUp(name:String)->String{
   var genre = ""
   let alert = UIAlertController(title: "What are you "+name+"?", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Boy", style: .default, handler: { action in
    genre = "Boy"
    self.afterPopup()
}))

   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Girl", style: .default, handler: { action in
    genre = "Girl"
    self.afterPopup()
}))

   self.present(alert, animated: true)
   return genre
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("This should appear before the alert")
        let a = showPopUp(name: "John)
}

func afterPopup(){
        print("This should appear after the response")
        print("John is a "+a)
        [...more code using variable 'a' ...]
}
```

Also, watch-out for presenting a popup in ViewDidLoad. if this view is being presented, you'll have a warning thrown (and may lead to weird behavior of app)